# How to display a stored session list of posts in index.ctp in CAKEPHP 2.10.15

Tags: cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.5

I want to store my saved session "POSTS" in an array so I can display them in Index.ctp. 
I save my posts in session by clicking on a link from Index.ctp.
I don't know how to display all my saved posts from session in Index.ctp.

I made the link " add To Favourites" from index.ctp, and the 2 functions in PostsController.

PostsController.php

```
public function addToFavourites($id = null){
        if(!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
        if(!$post){
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }
        $this->Session->write('sa', array($post));
        $data=$this->Session->read('sa');
        if(!empty($data)){
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your stuff has been saved.');
        }
        $this->redirect('/posts/index');
    }
    public function viewFavourites(){
        $data = $this->Session->read('sa');
        $data[] = // I want to store my saved session posts in an array; 
    }
```

Index.ctp

```
//It starts with a loop "foreach ($posts as $post) 
   <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
            array('action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id']))
            ; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <span>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Add to favourites',
                    array('controller' => 'posts',
                       'action' => 'addToFavourites',
                       $post['Post']['id']
                   ))
            ?>
        </span>
      </td>
      </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

“I expect the output of 5/2 to be 2.5, but the actual output is 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

I did not test the overall idea, but at least code that saves the favorite should be:

```php
// Reads current favorites
$data=$this->Session->read('sa');
// Add the new one
$data[] = $post;
// Saves it back into the session
$this->Session->write('sa', $data);
```

The above does NOT check/prevent if the same post is saved multiple times.